# Deleted roots of duplicates

Tags: support, duplicates, deleted-posts

I would like to know what happens to a Question B that was closed as duplicate of Question A, when Question A gets deleted? Is Question B reopened automatically? Should it be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I understand things, there is no connection between duplicates other than the link that is written into the duplicate question, so deletion of the root should not affect the duplicate.  I don't know if the link disappears.  But surely it's highly unlikely to delete a question that is the source of a duplicate for the reasons below.  Do you have a specific example in mind?

From [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/170190)

### When can't I delete my own post?

You can't delete answers that have been accepted.

You can't delete any question that:

- has an upvoted answer, or
- has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes), or
- has been closed less than 48 hours ago (to allow for possible reopening)

Comment: I have no concrete example at hand, but my question was triggered by an question yesterday regarding the basic cross-referencing scheme. I am sure I've read such a question before, and was looking for it to mark the new question as duplicate. But I could not find it anymore. That made me thinking up the situation described in my question.

Comment: Regarding the likeliness: I think such very basic questions might not get answers, or rather answers in the comments. So they can be deleted by the OP, although being the source of a duplicate.

Comment: @mafp It is unlikely that a "basic question" won't get an answer, and will be the target of a duplicate link. In such case, someone would answer one of those two questions, and mark the other one as a duplicate.